# Change background color of ion-item on click

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like to change the background color of the ion-item when the user clicks on it, as I could do.
Thanks in advance

example code:

```
 <ion-item (click)="openDetail(variant)">{{variant.ProductVariantName} 
  <ion-button slot="end" [hidden]="variant.ProductVariantValue.length==0" fill="clear" color="dark">
   <i [class]="variant.showDetail ? 'fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg':'fa fa arrow down fa-lg'"></i>
  </ion-button>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Hi, use [ngClass] instead of [class].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the official documentation here (look at "using Css" or "javascript") : https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables#ionic-variables

What you are looking for is changing this variable in your theming (or custom css)

```
--background-activated :    Background of the button when activated
```

Like :

```
.fancy-button {
   --background-activated: red;
}
```

I would not go for an angular solution if you only want to change the color of it. It's a Style related issue and as such you should solve it with the solutions provided by ionic for this specific usecase. Doing otherwise's only going to make you code more heavy to read and less performant.
But if you want to apply multiple class to you component after it's been clicked, then you need to use [ngClass]

Comment: I gave a class to the button and this css property but nothing

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts file:

declare a variable:

buttonColor: string = '#000';

Edit your HTML as:-

```
<ion-item (click)="openDetail(variant)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 
buttonColor}">{{variant.ProductVariantName}
<ion-button slot="end" [hidden]="variant.ProductVariantValue.length==0" 
fill="clear" color="dark">
 <i [class]="variant.showDetail ? 'fa fa-arrow-up fa-lg':'fa fa arrow down 
fa-lg'"></i>
</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

In your function do following changes:-

```
openDetail(variant){
   this.buttonColor = '#345465';
}
```